# Object as Interface without implements

Tags: c#, .net

I'm on a weird situation in which one of my methods has to receive either an **object** or a **dynamic** param (because it will receive about anything), but I do care that that class implements at least two methods.

Obviously, it would be great to just use and interface that all objects that want to be received on my method have to implement; sadly I cannot guarantee that...

I use a lot that object (and this two functions) in my classes and would want to make a reference to this object having a "type" of "IImplementsBothMethods" so I can use it after being casted knowing that it will not break.

What I would like is something like this:

```
public interface IImplementsBothMethods
{
  Method1();
  Method2();
}

public class ClassThatReceivesAnything
{
  IImplementsBothMethods obj;

  public ClassThatReceivesAnything([dynamic|object] unknownObject)
  {
     // unknownObject does not implement the interface
     obj = unknownObject as IImplementsBothMethods;
  }

  public void MethodThatDoesNotCare()
  {
    obj.Method1();
    obj.Method2();
  }
}
```

How can I accomplish this? the casting just returns null

Thanks

Comment: Am I misunderstanding your question?  Is public ClassThatReceivesAnything(IImplementsBothMethods obj) {} not an option?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you can't require incoming objects to implement an interface you can't have strongly typed code with direct reference (which makes sense as you seem to be  trying to implement [duck typing](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Duck_typing)).

You can create strongly typed wrapper that will shield the rest of your code from casts. The wrapper can either just rely on `dynamic`/reflection or uses some more complicated code like have unique instances for each of incoming type constructed with expression trees.

```
class WrapperToImplementBoth : IImplementsBothMethods
{
   private dynamic inner;
   public WrapperToImplementBoth(dynamic v)
   {
        inner = v;
   }

   // let dynamic handle calls, consider catching/logging exceptions  
   public void Method1() {inner.Method1()}; 
   public void Method2() {inner.Method2()};
}
```

Comment: Learned something new today... Duck Typing.